# I hold Indian passport and plan to visit Greece and then cross the border by road to Albania and Macedonia

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, greece, macedonia, albania

If I tick the multiple entry in the visa application, will I get it? If I enter Macedonia, showing them my exit ticket from Greece would do? There is a rule that states I should hold multi-entry visa and exit once from a Schengen state before visiting Albania/Macedonia. Will I qualify if I exit from Greece and immediately enter Albania/Macedonia?

Sorry for asking so many questions but I cannot find answers anywhere.

Comment: I believe the requirement that the visa be used is that this way the Albanians can rely on a Schengen-area border guard to have admitted you. This way, they don't need themselves to get lists of canceled Schengen visas or people who for some reason weren't able to be admitted. I expect the majority of people in your situation enter by land (or ferry) from Greece or Italy.

Answer (score 1):

Albania seems to require a used multi-entry Schengen Visa C for entry, North Macedonia also (multi is not stated explicitly)

- could find no working official Albanien / North Macedonia sites to confirm this

so this would be a valid reason to apply for one.

When entering through Greece, the Visa will be considered used.

Based on the available information, I would say yes.